# Can I somehow modify uikit's JS to allow me to use it with SvelteKit?

Tags: uikit, sveltekit

I have been working on this problem for a year now and can't find any resolution, so here goes nothing:

Since a recent update to Svelte or UIKit (sadly I don't know which) they seem to be conflicting with eachother. Svelte seems to want to control the DOM more aggressively than before, which interferes with UIKit's modifications. For example accordions and grids aren't displayed correctly.

My website footer should look like

[image: expected footer look on d20cay.com]

, but actually looks like

[image: actual footer look on d20cay.com]

All these examples and more can be seen on [d20cay.com](https://d20cay.com). The problem arises when you reload the page.

I tried

- more explicitly setting the appropriate classes, which fixes the alignment of the elements, but the content of the accordion is visible (on load) when closed.
- Contacting the UIKit developers with this issue. I didn't get a response.
- Contacting the Svelte developers with this issue. I got a response saying I should check with the UIKit developers.
- I tried figuring out the issue in the UIKit JavaScript and CSS, but I'm not good enough and/or the files are just too big.

Minimal working (or in this case not working) example can be found at [github.com/d20cay/sveltekit-test](https://github.com/d20cay/sveltekit-test).

At this point I'm just going to switch to a different CSS or UI framework. If anyone every finds a solution to this issue, be it in a few year's time I would very much appreciate a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, the problem is somewhere in the [SvelteKit hydration](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/appendix#hydration). It seems like the hydration is too aggressive and removes CSS classes that are not present in the HTML markup from svelte component.

As far as I understand, the following happens:

1. SvelteKit renders HTML on the server side (SSR).
2. `uikit.js` is loaded on the client side and applied to the rendered HTML (UIkit adds, for example, `uk-grid` class to elements with `uk-grid` attribute, registers `ResizeObserver`/`MutationObserver`, etc.).
3. SvelteKit hydrates the `index.svelte` component on the client side and this operation removes, for example, `uk-grid` class.
4. Without `uk-grid` class UIkit layout is broken.

## Workaround 1

You can start `uikit.js` always after hydration. For this move `uikit.js` to `src/lib/uikit.js` and import it on mount.

**src/routes/__layout.svelte:**

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    onMount(() => {
        import('$lib/uikit.js')
    })
</script>

<slot/>
```

## Workaround 2

Disable hydration for components that uses UIkit. **But with this workaround Svelte JavaScript expressions will not work on the client side.**

**src/routes/index.svelte:**

```
<script context="module">
    export const hydrate = false
</script>

<div class="uk-child-width-1-2" uk-grid>
    <div>test1</div>
    <div>test2</div>
</div>

<ul uk-accordion>
    <li>
        <a class="uk-accordion-title" href="#">Item 1</a>
        <div class="uk-accordion-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: d20cay, I investigate the problem further and changed my answer. Try to test the new workaround.

Comment: About workaround from my previous answer: whitespaces were probably not the problem, and my previous fix with `{' '}` probably worked in limited cases because it probably triggered an additional observer event.